# Fake a TTY on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file, automation

### Problem

My team would like to automate the process of logging people out of an application *(IBM FileNet)* using the security utility provided - `sec_tool`.
Most `sec_tool` commands can simply be piped in, making it easy to write a script with those commands. However, the `logoff` command does not.

*Manual Process:*

```
C:\Windows\system32>sec_tool

Type '?' for help

<SEC_tool>logoff user=test.user
```

*Piping Attempt:*

```
C:\Windows\system32>echo logoff user=test.user | sec_tool
  1 logoff user=test.user
Not a tty.
```

I am trying to find a way to automate this process by faking a tty. This manual task is taking time out of our daily duties and we would benefit greatly from scripting this process.

Comment: [SEC_tool, specifically, is designed to check if it is being run in a script and disallows some commands.](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21318334)

Comment: I get that. My goal here is to circumvent default behavior.

Comment: You found a way?